# How to define PHPStorm live template variable as lowercase value of another variable?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I want to make a template like `something $NAME$ other $LOWNAME$` so that when I use it, I'm taken to $NAME$ input list and $LOWNAME$ is automatically filled with decapitalized value of $NAME$ I input. For example, I print "Client" to $NAME$ and the value of $LOWNAME$ is "client". Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If by "decapitalizing" you mean to lower case **only first letter** then YES, otherwise No (as there is no function for lower casing all characters).

1. Template: `something $NAME$ other $LOWNAME$`
2. Click on "Edit variables" button
3. In "Expression" column for "LOWNAME" variable enter this: `decapitalize(NAME)` and tick/check "Skip if defined" box

Now when template will be expanded, and if you enter "CapitalShip" for `$NAME$` variable, the 
`$LOWNAME$` will automatically become "capitalShip"

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html

Comment: Thanks. I was trying the same thing with `decapitalize($NAME$)` - it silently didn't work

Comment: Make sure to order your variables (in "Edit variables") so that LOWNAME comes after NAME.

Answer (score 5):

To do this with file templates (without expressions) in PHPStorm you can use Java functions in combination with [Apache Velocity Template Language](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Velocity_Template_Language_VTL:_An_Introduction):

```
#set( $name = ${NAME} )
<?php

class ${NAME} extends Model{
  protected \$table = '$name.toLowerCase()';
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I've had some trouble with escaped \$, so for people in the same spot, adding a $ sign might also be done with `${DS}`